# How to find perticular month of files by using Unix commamnd?

Tags: unix

Please tell the command, how to find pertucular month of files among all the files from the various months

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please show us what you have attempted previously?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command (not sure if there is a inbuilt utility available)

```
ls -lrt|grep "Apr"|sed -n "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)$/\2/p"
```

The below works too

> `find . -type f -printf '%Tm %p\n'|awk '$1=="04"{print $2}'`